# ASP.NET MVC, Should I keep entire app in areas?

Tags: model-view-controller, areas

Imagine that I have a store. I have an admin side to the store located in an area called "Admin".

This makes sense.

But should I also have an area called "Public" for the public facing side of the store?

Or should I just leave the public side at the root of MVC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if there is a definitive answer to this one, but I prefer to have the public/core site in the root of the application. I tend to look at Areas as an extension of the core focus.

Rich